# Need maven dependency plugin to build dependency locally

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm using `mvn dependency:tree` to print out dependency of my project.

I have 2 pom.xml in my project, 1st pom.xml genearates `a.jar`, 2nd project uses `a.jar`

I'm removing some unused dependencies from 1st pom.xml. But when I ran `mvn dependency:tree` on 2nd project, I can see `a.jar` is in the dependent list, but it still depends on those dependencies already removed from 1st project locally. So I guess when the command is run, a.jar is pulled from the remote repo so it still contains the dependencies removed locally?

If it's true, how to get a dependncy tree from local pom.xml so that all local changes are reflected?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the POM of 2nd project: how does it reference project1?

Comment: Problem seems to be solved by `-o` option which run offline